# Lining up a sub menu with it's parent li

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to set up a sub menu where the first item lines up with it's parent's li item, is there a way of doing this without using negative margins on the 2nd ul (#innerNav). My code can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/ueEEa/2/

---

```
#parentNav {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  width: 160px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #999;
}

#parentNav > li, #parentNav > li > #innerNav > li {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px dashed #999;
  display: block;
}

#parentNav li #innerNav {
  display: none;
}

#parentNav > li:hover >  {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 160px;
  width: 160px;
  padding: 0px;
  position:absolute
}

<div>
    <ul id="parentNav">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2
            <ul id="innerNav">
                <li>Item 2.1</li>
                <li>Item 2.2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you against using negative margins?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by giving the child nav menu `display: inline-block` instead of `block`.

Doing that means that its left edge will be normally flush against the right edge of the parent `<li>` element, so to fix that we also need to give `display: relative` to the top menu and `left: 160px` (equal to the top menu width) to the child nav menu.

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/ueEEa/3/)**.

Comment: Thank you, but I find this messes up again once I put an "a" around each item in my list. http://jsfiddle.net/HXBZ2/

Comment: You can probably work around that too, but at this point I have a counter question: you ask a question, get an answer and then *change the question*. Is it surprising that the answer no longer works?